# Root Alcatel One Touch Pop 4s

Tags: root-access

Are there any tools to root a Alcatel One Touch Pop 4s (Android 6.0), I already tryed Kingroot and Famaroot but both do not work like on other Alcatel phones

Answer (score 0):

You can try KingoRoot instead of kingroot....

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! This post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. How did it solve the issue? Where to find it? What are the steps to perform?

Comment: Already tryed that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... It will work.....

1. Download Super-Root.apk for Alcatel Pop 4s from this link : http://downloadsafe.org/file/0yF980
2. Connect your device to your PC using the USB cable.
3. Copy the Super-Root.apk over to the root of your SD card.
4. Once it’s been copied, disconnect your device from your PC.
5. Head to Menu>>Settings>>Security on your device and enable the Unknown sources option.
6. Open the File Manager app on your device and install the app you copied earlier to your device.
7. Once the app’s been installed, launch it from your App Drawer.
8. Select Install SuperSU from the first dropdown menu.
9. Select exploit, tap on it in the app.
10. The app should begin rooting your device, shouldn’t take too long to finish.
11. Reboot your device once it’s been rooted.
12. You’re all done! Enjoy

Comment: Not downloadable with "Quick Offer" thing, can you upload it via dropbox or something like that?